# Probability for repeated incidents .

Tags: probability, dice

I had problems on understanding the following problem :

> A die is continuously thrown until 4 is obtained.  What is the probability that the dice is thrown an even number of times?

**Here** , a solution states that probability is :
$$\frac{4}{6}\times \frac{2}{6}+\frac{4}{6}\times \frac{4}{6}\times \frac{4}{6}\times \frac{2}{6} + ...$$
$$=\frac{2}{5}$$

**I didn't understand why such process was used and what's the the concept behind it?**

Another problem :

> (ii) If a biased coin is tossed two times  repeatedly , then what is the probability of occurring HH?

**Can I do the problem (ii) similarly like (i) as** :
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{4}+ ...$$

Comment: In the first one it is just asking for the probability that a geometric random variable is even, but the formula itself is wrong. It would be right if two of the outcomes on the die stopped the process rather than one. The second problem is ambiguous: what happens when the overall sequence of throws is THHT? Did HH occur or not?

Comment: The answer to the first question posted by OP should be $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} + \dotsb = \frac{5}{11}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the formula used either.

Method I:  infinite series.

The probability that the die is thrown exactly $2n$ times is $ \left(\frac 56 \right)^{2n-1}\times \frac 16$  so the answer is $$\frac 16 \times \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 56 \right)^{2n-1}=\frac 5{11}$$

Method II:  recursion

Let $p$ denote the answer.  The first roll is either a $4$ or it isn't.  Hence $$p=\frac 16\times 0+\frac 56\times (1-p)\implies p=\frac 5{11}$$

Comment: I don't understand the recursion method,  why does $0$ come?

Comment: If you throw a $4$ first then you failed (as $1$ is an odd number).  Thus the probability of success along that branch is $0$.

Comment: Wait... What if I get a 4 at the first throw ?

Comment: Then you have lost, as it took you one roll and one is odd.  That's the branch that leads to $0$...as I said in my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the first problem doesn't say "a die is thrown until a number higher than 4 is obtained"? That would fit with the probability given, where the first term is the probability of exactly two throws (1-4 then 5-6), the next term four throws (1-4, 1-4, 1-4, 5-6) and so on.

For the problem as you've stated it, the actual answer (by a similar method) is $\frac 5{11}$, since in this case at each throw the probability of stopping is $\frac16$ and the probability of continuing is $\frac56$.

The second problem doesn't make much sense. How biased is the coin? When do you stop tossing it? If you keep going forever you will (with probability $1$) get HH eventually.

Comment: If I keep tossing till infinity,  then it'll be $1$ , right?  But it doesn't account for the first one,  why?

Answer (score 0):

1. See, that the probabilty of throwing $4$ in $k$-th throw ($k\geq 1$)is equal to:
   $$p(k)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}$$
   So we have to sum up all the probabilities for even $k$:
   $$P=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p(2n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^{2n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5}{36}\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{n}=\frac{5}{36}\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}}=\frac{5}{11}$$
2. Tossing a coin two times makes the probability of $HH$ equal to $p(H)^2$.